# numbers from string to char array to int array

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, integer

I have a string input and I'm trying to convert it to a character array then store the numbers from that array in a manner that will let me use them in a credit card program. This is how i am currently trying to do it.

I'm currently getting Null Pointer Exception at :

```
charDigits[x - invalid] = charInput[x];
```

I need to be able to use the integers on the credit card algorithm from a string input.

```
public class testFunction {
    private char[] charInput;
    private char[] charDigits;
    private int[] intInput;
    private int invalid = 0;
    private String input = "125-6543-3356";

    public testFunction()
    {
        charInput = input.toCharArray();

        for(int x = 0; x < charInput.length; x++)
        {
            if (charInput[x] == '0' || charInput[x] == '1' || charInput[x] == '2' || charInput[x] == '3' || charInput[x] == '9' ||
                charInput[x] == '4' || charInput[x] == '5' || charInput[x] == '6' || charInput[x] == '7' || charInput[x] == '8')
            {               
                charDigits[x - invalid] = charInput[x];
            }
            else
            {
                invalid++;
            }
            System.out.println("charDigits: " + x + ": " + charDigits[x] );
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < charDigits.length; i++)
        {
            intInput[i] = Integer.parseInt(charDigits[i] + "");
        }
    }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            testFunction test = new testFunction();
        }
}
```

Comment: try using something like `if(c >= '0' && c <= '9')` rather than chaining all those `||` together.  As you can see [here](http://www.asciitable.com/) the code points for `0` to `9` are contiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see you initializing `charDigits` anywhere. Its initial value is `null`, hence accessing it like `charDigits[i]` would raise an NPE (you should have been able to easily deduce this based on the documentation of [`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)). You'll need to initialize `charDigits` first to an array of whatever size it should be (looks like max size will be `charInput.length`):

```
charDigits = new char[charInput.length];
```

However, to make the rest of your logic work, you'll also want to keep track of how many digits in `charDigits` are actually valid (since ultimately it can be shorter than `charInput`). You have a lot of options:

- Consider doing `valid++` in the positive case instead of `invalid++` in the negative case, and index by `charDigits[valid]` instead of `[x - invalid]`. At the end of the loop, `valid` will contain the number of characters copied to `charDigits`, and `intInput` can be initialized accordingly.
- Since the elements of `charDigits` will be initialized to `0`, stop copying to `intInput` when `charDigits[i] == 0`.
- Use a dynamic array for `charDigits` (e.g. an `ArrayList<Character>`) and append as needed.
- Use a `StringBuilder` or something instead for `charDigits`, and append as needed.
- Etc.